# Why is Array<String> the chosen parameter type for the main function in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

The main function in kotlin:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) { 
  println("Hello, world!") 
}
```

Why is an Array passed in?

Comment: Why explicitly an array or why the parameter is there at all?

Answer (score 6):

The signature of `main` is based on what the Java Virtual Machine [expects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1):

> The method `main` must be declared `public, static, and void`. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is **array of String**. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> public static void main(String... args)
> ```

This is what the Kotlin compiler compiles your main function to. As of Kotlin 1.3, the explicit `Array<String>` can be omitted but will still be available in the byte code.

Comment: Thanks. But is there a reason why they chose `String[]` to be the type passed through?

Comment: You typically start a jvm program like this: `java [...] ClassX arg1 arg2 arg3` which will make the args available inside the `String []` of ClassX's main

Comment: What other type would you use to pass the command line arguments?

Comment: It's the same for other languages like C: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Answer (score 1):

`Collections` were not there in JAVA 1. Hence, `Array` was the default choice. Also the arguments provided from Command Line are in string format, hence we use `Array<String>`. Kotlin, to maintain interoperability with JAVA, followed the same convention. But, with the update to Kotlin 1.3, that too has been omitted. Now you can use `main()` function without passing `args:Array<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

The array contains the command line arguments passed to your program.

You can also omit it, if you do not want to use them, i.e. you can also just write:

```
fun main() {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```

I am already too late to link to the [JLS for `Test.main`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) here ([s1m0nw1 already did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325625/6202869); I just prepared and went away ;-))

But nonetheless I want to add something regarding the choice for `String` (i.e. my opinion why `String` was chosen): it's probably the most common denominator for all the possible command line arguments. `Any`/`Object` is too broad; you can only pass numbers or strings in the command line to a program (pipes are handled differently). But having a number type is too narrow, so the only acceptable type that remains is `String` which can represent both. Still you need to parse numbers if you want to use them, but that's better then interpreting a string out of numbers ;-)

Comment: If the main function doesn't do anything then why is it needed? I assumed the main function executed the other functions.

Comment: No wait... the `main`-function is actually the entry point to your application ... or in other words: without the `main`-function your program will not run... with it you can for example just call: `java TestKt` which will then run your program (if the `main` was placed in a file named `Test.kt` and was compiled to a `class`-file, etc. pp)

Comment: so for example: if you "run" your file using your IDE, without a `main`-function it will not run at all (exceptions to this exist, e.g. you can also run tests and other things...)

Answer (score 0):

Your are defining the entry point of an application. in this case, an application will start running from the main function. Passing the argument Array of type String.