# Why Kotlin allow write main function with no arguments?

Tags: kotlin

Recently, I started to learn `Kotlin` and figured out that the `main()` function may be written without arguments like this:

```
fun main() {
    dayOfWeek()
}
```

How is this possible and what `Kotlin` is doing under the hood? 
`Java` doesn't allow us to do so.

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent to learn new things rather than using stackoverflow to fix your bugs :D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of main is based on what the Java Virtual Machine expects:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main
>   of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an
>   array of strings.
>
> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of
>   String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> public static void main(String[] args) public static void
>   main(String... args)

[Ref1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54325625/4370279)

So yes, we should define an array string param in the `main` method. But, as you asked,

> How is this possible and what Kotlin does under the hood?

Let's see,

**Kotlin Code**

```
// fileName : Main.kt
fun main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

**Compiled Java Code**

```java
public final class MainKt {
   public static final void main() {
      String var0 = "Hello World!";
      System.out.println(var0);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
}
```

As you can see, in the compiled Java code, Kotlin uses method overloading to call `main` method with `String[]` argument. From this, we can understand that the Koltin simply helps us to save time and make syntax more readable.

Internally, Kotlin calls the main method with `String[]` argument.

**Tip**

If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, you can use the built-in Kotlin tools to see the compiled Java version of the Kotlin code.

1. `Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode`
2. Click on the `Decompile` button

You can find simple guide with screenshots from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52983100/4370279)

Comment: Which IDE you're using for Kotlin development ? IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's the JVM launcher which calls `main(String[])` and of course it doesn't know anything about Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

Other languages like C/C++ allow a `main` function with empty parameter list. Under the hood they are just usual `main` methods with the parameters being ignored. This feature is purely syntactic to simplify short programs and demo-ware